# Use the definition of derivative to find $f'(1)$ for $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

This is analysis.. So I am using the definition that 
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
$$

So far I have, 
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2+1}}}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}  \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{x-1}
$$
Now how do I make the correlation from there to the real derivative of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next few steps involve getting a common denominator on top, reducing it to a single fraction, and then multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate of the numerator.